# Why to Wrap HTML code in PHP tags

Tags: php

I have seen couple of php scripts wrapping around HTML tags. Are there any benefits to follow this technique OR its better to keep them separate.

DEMO (page.php)

```
  <?php
  <html>
   <?php
  <head></head>
   <body>
   ?>

   </body>
   <?php

   ?>
    </html  ?>

   ?>
```

Comment: There's no benefit to the example you give, since it'll produce a parser error and not display anything.

Comment: @Brian: But what he's asking about is very unclear given an entirely invalid demo.  He says he's seen something in practice, but what he's showing can't be used in practice.  So what has he seen?  What is he asking?

Answer (score 5):

Your example is not valid, the only way of putting HTML content in your PHP script, is to output it with whether `echo` or `print`.

`PHP` is a server-side scripting language, you need to respect the syntax of it or the script won't compile.

Answer (score 4):

Well that's completely invalid and will instantly fail on account of an unexpected `<`.

Answer (score 3):

Please read http://php.net/language.basic-syntax.phpmode It explains how HTML and PHP can be interleafed.

Comment: The link you provided is dead.

Comment: Fixing it. After 7 years something like this might happen.

Answer (score 1):

You can't and I would advice you to keep it seperated as much as possible (there is a reason for templating engines such as Smarty) to keep your code logical and clear (and.. to genuinly make sense)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest php tags inside php tags, as you are doing in your example.

Other than that: It probably depends on what your needs are.  In general, try to keep PHP logic separate from HTML.

I used to mix a lot of  php blocks between HTML code, and I used a lot of PHP strings for every line of HTML code I wanted to store.  Untill the day when I realized that this also works - note I use one php block for the entire page:

```
<?php

  /* php logic here */

  $html = '

    /* Cut and past all your normal HTML code here, but make sure double quotes are used for all the attributes. */

  ';

 echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: For fast convert parts of html to **PHP echo or print statements** you can use some of free online tool like [HTML to PHP](https://wtools.io/html-to-php-converter) just past your html code and click convert and no more "escape" issues.

Answer (score 0):

The code as you have it will not work at all. If you were going to do something like this, it should look more like:

```
<?php
    echo "<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>

        </body>
    </html>";
?>
```

But this is really only useful if you are planning to generate HTML code using PHP in order to use PHP variables or useful PHP functions, etc. Like:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET["test"] == "hello")
        $var = "1";
    else
        $var = "2";

    echo "<html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            var is set to {$var}
        </body>
    </html>";
?>
```

This is, of course, a very basic example.